# RIA base DomainService implementation for Subsonic 3?

Tags: subsonic, wcf-ria-services

So i'm fairly new to both SubSonic and RIA Services. I've done the RIA walkthrough for the HR app and it all looks good, but I'm not quite about creating a DomainService base class for Subsonic.

The samples [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=RiaServices&DownloadId=5731) describe creating a custom base class for your DAL but I wondering if there was already anything out in the wild that did this for Subsonic 3 SimpleRepository?

Additionally how should one handle generating all the DomainService classes that correspond to each class in the DAL? T4 templates?

Answer (score 0):

Well I have since solved this problem. I thought it was related to how I was implementing my domain service, but since the November beta release of RIA Services I've realised it was probably related to bugs in the previous July version.